# Return permission in number form of file/ directory

Tags: command-line, permissions

Is there a way to return the file permissions in the format in which they are modified using `chmod`?

For example

```
chmod 755 thisdir
```

then

```
commandx thisdir
```

Would return `755`, where commandx is some command used.

Answer (score 3):

Use `stat` with `%a` format specifier (`%n` is for file name):

```
stat -c '%a : %n' scipy
```

From `man stat`:

```
%a     access rights in octal
%n     file name
```

**Example:**

```
% stat -c '%a : %n' foobar    
2755 : foobar
```

---

For re-usability, create the following function (save it in a shell startup file e.g. in `~/.bashrc` for `bash`):

```
% octperm () { stat -c '%a' "$@" ;}

% octperm foobar
2755
```